# Dynamically adding FormArray to the FormGroup is not working Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using **Angular 8** and **Reactive Form**.

I want to add `FormArray` control to the main form group.

The component is

```
export class RsvpComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    });
  }

  public addGuest() {
    if (!this.form.get('guests')) {
      this.addGuestControl();
    }

    this.getGuestControlArray().push(this.guestControl());
  }

  private addGuestControl() {
    this.form.addControl('guests', new FormArray([]));
  }

  private getGuestControlArray() {
    return this.form.get('guests') as FormArray;
  }

  private guestControl(): FormGroup {
    const guestGroup = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    });

    return guestGroup;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('submitted: ', this.form.value);
  }
}
```

The `addGuest` is called on click of a button. By default there will be no guests hence, no `guests` control in the form.

On calling the method `addGuest`, it first checks if `guests` control is there, if not then adds the control first which is a `FormArray` type.

This works fine on first click and controls are added, but on clicking of the `submit` button, `onSubmit` is called and the added guest data is not in the value.

When calling again `addGuest` the check for `guests` control fails.

Stackbliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bipdyu

The weird condition: The code is working in the Stackblitz, but when I copy the same code in my component, (removing everything), it's not working.

Comment: If possible then provide stackblitz

Comment: I have added the stackblitz url in the question. But it seems weird, that same thing is working in Stackblitz but not in my app.

Comment: Check for console error

Comment: In your template, `formControlName='guests'`(or [formControl]="...") is bound to a component or to a DOM element?

Comment: @Andrei The controls are not registered yet.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale There is no error in the console. Only the logs I have consoled in the application.

Comment: I figured that the component is loaded again. ie., `ngOnInit` method is called again when clicking the button. The component is rendered using `*ngIf` in a `*ngFor` loop.

Comment: Create the same scenario in the stackblitz? with that *ngIf or *ngFor?

Comment: *Dynamically adding FormArray to the FormGroup is not working Angular* sure it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Change Detection Strategy in Angular.

Same has been answered here: [Angular @Input binding using function calling multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59686730/3719167)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you would need to change your `guestControl()` method to return a `FormControl` instead of a `FormGroup`. A `FormGroup` cannot track a internal value it only acts as a superiour structure to 'group' (!) your `FormControl`s. For any actual value you would need those.

```
private guestControl(): FormControl {
  const guestControl = this.fb.control('', Validators.required);
  return guestControl;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid syntax. The first argument of `FormControl` should be `formState`, which can be either a primitive value(ex: `''`/`null`) or a boxed value(`{ value: '', disabled: false }`). [Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1168-L1177)

Comment: If it's the case, then remove the return type should work. But it's not working.

Comment: You are totally right. the above should fix the syntax

Comment: *A FormGroup cannot track a internal value it* well whole form is a `FormGroup` and yet it does track values and states.